# Hadoop setInputPathFilter error

Tags: hadoop, io

I am using Hadoop 0.20.2 (that cannot be changed) and I want to add a filter to my input path. The data looks as follows:

```
/path1/test_a1
/path1/test_a2
/path1/train_a1
/path1/train_a2
```

and I only want to process all files with *train* in them.

A look at the FileInputFormat class suggests to use:

```
 FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(Job job, Class<? extends PathFilter> filter)
```

and this is where my problem starts, since [PathFilter](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/PathFilter.html) is an interface - of course, I can extend the interface but then I still do not have an implementation. So instead, I implemented the interface:

```
class TrainFilter implements PathFilter
{
   boolean accept(Path path)
   {
      return path.toString().contains("train");
   }
}
```

When I use TrainFilter as PathFilter the code compiles, however when I run it, I get an exception as the input path is screwed up. Without setting the filter, my code runs through all files that are below /path1, however, when setting the filter, it throws the error:

```
InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist hdfs://localhost:9000/path1
```

Here is how I set it up in the driver code:

```
job.setMapperClass(....class);
job.setInputFormatClass(....class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(...class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(job, TrainFilter.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/path1/"));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/path2/"));
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Any suggestions of what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT: I found the problem. The first call to the PathFilter is always the directory itself (/path1) and since it does not contain ("train"), the directory itself is invalid and thus the exception is thrown. Which brings me to another question: how can I test if an arbitrary path is a directory? For all I know, I need a reference to the FileSystem, which is not one of the default parameters of PathFilter.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you may try to loop through all of the files in the given directory and check if the file names begin with *train*. E.g:

```
        Job job = new Job(conf, "myJob");
        List<Path> inputhPaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

        String basePath = "/user/hadoop/path";
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        FileStatus[] listStatus = fs.globStatus(new Path(basePath + "/train*"));
        for (FileStatus fstat : listStatus) {
            inputhPaths.add(fstat.getPath());
        }

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,
                (Path[]) inputhPaths.toArray(new Path[inputhPaths.size()]));
```

Comment: @Claudia It seems to me that when applying a custom filter and there's no match you'll end up in an `IOException ("Input path does not exist")`. This could be definitely avoided by overriding `FileInputFormat#listStatus(JobContext job)`, as the javadoc states:
`,,Subclasses may override to, e.g., select only files matching a regular expression. "` but I think the above mentioned solution can
be applied more easily.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix, You can blacklist paths instead of whitelisting like return false if path contains "test"

Answer (score 1):

You can get a FileSystem instance by having your Filter implement the Configurable interface (or extend the Configured class), and create a fileSystem instance variable in the setConf method:

```
class TrainFilter extends Configured implements PathFilter
{
   FileSystem fileSystem;

   boolean accept(Path path)
   {
      // TODO: use fileSystem here to determine if path is a directory
      return path.toString().contains("train");
   }

   public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
     if (conf != null) {
       fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but it helped me find an answer to excluding paths when all the examples of it failed me, such as documented [here](https://holynull.gitbooks.io/oreilly-hadoop-the-definitive-guide-4th-edition/content/page/querying-the-filesystem.html).

I just want to warn about the answer that @ChrisWhite gave, because I am working on Hadoop 3.3.0 API and using setConf threw a NullPointerException when I was about to pull something out of the configuration.
I found that instead I'll keep the `extends Configured` in the PathFilter signature but just put `getConf().get(<your configuration parameter name>)` whenever you need what you need from the job configuration.

So, my excluding PathFilter looks like this:

```
public static class ExcludedPathsFilter extends Configured implements PathFilter {

    public boolean accept(Path includePathGlob){
        //debugging
        System.out.println("excludedPath parameter is "+getConf().get("excludedPath")+", includePath parameter is "+includePathGlob.toString()+" and !includePathGlob.toString().contains(getConf().get(\"excludedPath\")) is "+!includePathGlob.toString().contains(getConf().get("excludedPath")));
        return !includePathGlob.toString().contains(getConf().get("excludedPath"));
    }

}
```