# What is the most efficient way to make sure hadoop skips certain input files?

Tags: hadoop

I have a hadoop application that -depending on a parameter- only needs certain (few!) input files from the input directory. My question is now: where is the best place (read: as early as possible) to skip those files? Right now I customized a RecordReader to take care of that, but I was wondering whether I could skip those files sooner? In my current implmentation hadoop still has a huge overhead due to irrelevant files.

Maybe I should add that it is very easy to see whether I need a certain input file. If the filename starts with a parameter, it is needed. Structuring my input directory hierachically might be a solution, but one that is not very likely for my project since every files would end up lonely in a certain directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd propose you to filter out the input files by applying the appropriate pattern on the input `Path`s as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13454344/1050422 
Note that this solution doesn't consider subdirectories. Alter it
to be able to recursively visit all subdirectories, within the base path.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with using the setInputPaths() method on TextInputFormat to specify a single String containing comma-separated file names.

Comment: do you mean FileInputFormat.setInputPaths? I thought along those lines, where I would maybe use a regex that matches certain input files. I can't find anything that would allow that though...

Comment: Sorry.  Yes, that's what I meant.  If you want a programmable API you could use setInputPathFilter(job,ABC.class) where ABC is a class you write that (a) implements PathFilter and (b) would do the regex test.

Comment: @KarelV You may have look at my answer in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13454344/1050422

Comment: I recall with setInputPathFilter() that if your input path (specified in setInputPath()) is a folder, which it probably is, that your ABC filter class needs to be ready for a recursive walk-through of the entire directory structure under the specified folder.  My first attempt got choked on directory names and I had to add logic to filter those out.  It's almost like a visitor pattern.

Comment: @Lorand Bendig: your solutions seems to work. Thanks. If you copy-paste your anser on my question I can accapt it as answer. Thank you too Chris Gerken, Lorands solution seemed simpler.